# How to get the unique results from mongoose using $setUnion and $group?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

[image: sample documents of mongodb]

I tried something like below but dint get the expected result , This should work if the fields are not an array

```
 // union of includes and excludes as excludesAndExcludes
    getIncludesAndExcludes: (req, res)=>{
        console.log('called setunion');
        experienceModel.aggregate([
            { $group: {_id : {includes:"$includes", excludes:"$excludes"}}},            
            { $project: { includesAndExcludes: { $setUnion: [ "$_id.includes", "$_id.excludes" ] }, _id:0 } }  
        ], (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(error); 
            } else {
                res.json(data);
            }         
        })
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most efficiently exclude the document if neither array has any element via [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) and most importantly you are going to need [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) to replace with a `null` where arrays don't exist.

```js
experienceModel.aggregate([
  // Don't include documents that have no arrays
  { "$match": { 
    "$or": [
      { "includes.0": { "$exists": true } },
      { "excludes.0": { "$exists": true } }
    ]
  },
  // Join the arrays and exclude the nulls
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "list": {
      "$setDifference": [
        { "$setUnion": [ 
          { "$ifNull": [ "$includes", [null] ] },
          { "$ifNull": [ "$excludes", [null] ] }
        ]},
        [null]
      ]
  }},

  // Unwind. By earlier conditions the array must have some entries
  { "$unwind": "$list" },

  // And $group on the list values as the key to produce distinct results
  { "$group": { "_id": "$list" }
],(err, data) => {
   // rest of code
})
```

So the first [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) is to filter so that at least one array must be present as a logic rule, which also possibly speeds things up. Next you join the arrays with [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/), being careful to replace with an array of a single element `[null]` using [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) if the field was not present. If you **did not do this** then any [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) result would be `null` rather than listing entries of either array. So that is quite important.

Since it is possible for the output of [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) to have a `null` item in it's list, you can remove that with [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/), which is the shortest form of filter you can write and works well with "sets".

All that really remains is to "de-normalize" the array in each document to single documents of each element using [`$unwind][6]`, and we don't need new options like `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` because all the logic above already took car of that. And then the final [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is simply done on those values in order to produce "unique" output, which is what the `_id` key in a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) statement is for.

If you want, then you can even just strip down the result from aggregate to a simple list of strings for your response using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example):

```js
data = data.map( d => d._id );
```

Then all your service returns is an array of strings, and no embedded structures.

```js
[
  "Breakfast"
  "Airport Pickup"
  "Dinner"
  "Accomodation"
]
```